# Doubt on 3d analog on gaussian integral for QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, integration

It is a well known fact that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx e^{-x^2}=\sqrt{\pi}.$$ These types of integrals are commonly encountered in the study of Quantum Mechanics and Quantum Field Theory. I am comfortable with calculating these types of integrals using standard methods, but recently stumbled across an integral that I cant seem to work out. In my QFT text we have the Gaussian smearing function $$f(\vec{k},\vec{k'})=Ne^{-\frac{(\vec{k}-\vec{k'})^2}{2\sigma^2}}.$$ Moreover this function arises from wanting to calculate the inner product $$\langle 1_{\vec{k}}|1_{\vec{k}} \rangle$$, where $$|1_{\vec{k}} \rangle=\int \frac{d^3k'}{(2\pi)^3}f(\vec{k},\vec{k'})|1_{\vec{k'}} \rangle.$$ Calculating the bra and inserting the definition of our ket we have that $$\langle 1_{\vec{k}}|1_{\vec{k}} \rangle=\int \frac{d^3k'}{(2\pi)^3} \int \frac{d^3k''}{(2\pi)^3}f(k,k')f(k,k'')\langle 1_{k'}|1_{k''} \rangle$$ $$=\int \frac{d^3k'}{(2\pi)^3} \int \frac{d^3k''}{(2\pi)^3}f(k,k')f(k,k'')(2\pi)^3\delta(k''-k')$$ $$=\int \frac{d^3k'}{(2\pi)^3} \int \frac{d^3k''}{(2\pi)^3}f(k,k')f(k,k')$$ $$=\int \frac{d^3k'}{(2\pi)^3}N^2e^{-\frac{(k-k')^2}{\sigma^2}}.$$ Now to evaluate this integral I immediately thought the $()$ in the exponent might be shorthand notation for the magnitude of the difference of our two 3-momentum vectors $k,k'$ but then thought it might not be. If thats the case then I would think to use spherical coordinates to evaluate this integral, that is take $d^3k'=4\pi k^2dk',k \in [0,\infty)$. I have tried this but with no luck. In the book that this integral shows up in, the answer is given as $$\int \frac{d^3k'}{(2\pi)^3}N^2e^{-\frac{(k-k')^2}{\sigma^2}}=\frac{N^2\pi^{3/2}b^3}{(2\pi)^3}.$$ After doing research, this is exactly the result of the 3d analog of the Gaussian integral, that is $$\int d^3r e^{\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{b^2}}=\pi^{3/2}b^3.$$ I can understand this because we just take $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2$ and then split up the integral into the integral over the 3 spherical coordinates. However, I am not so sure how to apply that fact with this integral. I have one main thing confusing me, the $(k-k')^2$ in the exponent. By $(k-k')^2$ do they mean $|k-k'|^2$ or literally $(k-k')^2=k^2-2k\cdot k'+(k')^2$? Furthermore, if they mean the magnitude (which I have a feeling is correct), that would imply that $$\int \frac{d^3k'}{(2\pi)^3}N^2e^{-\frac{(k-k')^2}{\sigma^2}}=\int \frac{d^3k'}{(2\pi)^3}N^2e^{-\frac{(k_1-k'_1)^2+(k_2-k'_2)^2+(k_3-k'_3)^2}{\sigma^2}}.$$ At this point, I wanna say we can use spherical coordinates but I do not know how to proceed doing so because of the $(k_1-k'_1)^2+(k_2-k'_2)^2+(k_3-k'_3)^2$ we have in the integral. How would we proceed to evaluate this thing? I have tried many different approaches but still havnt found an answer that matches up with the one provided. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suspect the definition of $\left|1_{\vec{k}}\right>$ you gave makes little sense since it is defined in terms of itself. Or at lest the notation is confusing. I think you want to defined a smeared one particle state (wavepacket) in terms of a delta-like one particle state, but you can't use the same symbol for both

Answer (score 3):

1. $|k - k^\prime|^2$ and $k^2 - 2k \cdot k^\prime + k^{\prime 2}$ are the same thing.
2. Integrals from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ are translation invariant so make the substitution $k^{\prime\prime} = k - k^\prime$ and there you go.

Comment: Thanks! So for the change in the differential would we just have $d^3k''=d^3k'$?

Comment: @aygx $d^3k''= -d^3k'$ in this case

Comment: @Triatticus I figured that out by recalling the jacobian transformation from k' and k to k''. Applying that we have $$\int\frac{d^3k'}{(2\pi)^3}N^2e^{-\frac{(k-k')^2}{\sigma^2}}=-\int\frac{d^3k''}{(2\pi)^3}N^2e^{\frac{-(k'')^2}{\sigma^2}}=-\frac{4\pi N^2}{(2\pi)^3}\int_0^{\infty}dk''(k'')^2e^{\frac{(k'')^2}{\sigma^2}}$$.
The integral
$$\int_0^{\infty}dk''(k'')^2e^{\frac{(k'')^2}{\sigma^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}\sigma^3$$. Then we get the final answer to go like $\frac{N^2 \pi^{3/2}b^3}{(2\pi)^3}$. But where does the - sign out front from the volume element cancel to yield a positive solution?

Comment: The substitution you're using reverses the limits of integration three times. This is why most books tell you to keep them the same but use the absolute value of the Jacobian.